# Поочередная анимация JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, анимация

Есть 4 блока.При клике на первый блок,анимация запускается и блоки поочередно появляются.
Для этого написал такую функцию:

```js
    jQuery('#map_open').on('click',function () {
        jQuery('.map_item__block_1').animate({
                height : 'toggle',
                opacity: 'toggle'
            },300,"linear",function () {
                jQuery('.map_item__block_2').animate({
                    height : 'toggle',
                    opacity: 'toggle'
                },300,"linear",function () {
                    jQuery('.map_item__slider_block').animate({
                        height : 'toggle',
                        opacity: 'toggle'
                    },400,function(){
                      jQuery('.slider__block').slick();
                    });
                })
            }
        )
    });
```

Как ее можно сократить, и сделать  универсальной,и правильной?

[Пример на codepen](https://codepen.io/jSas/pen/VWRPNE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуйста:

```
    var animateFn = {height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle'},
        animateDuration = 300,
        blocks = ['.map_item__block_1', '.map_item__block_2', '.map_item__slider_block', initCarousel];

jQuery('#map_open').on('click', function animateOnClick() {
    var block = blocks.shift();
    if (typeof block === "function") {
        block();
        animateOnClick();
    } else {
        animate(block, animateOnClick);
    }
});

function animate(block, cb) {
    jQuery(block).animate(animateFn, animateDuration, cb);
}

function initCarousel() {

}
```

По клику функция рекурсивно проходит по массиву `blocks`: берет первый элемент массива, и передает его в функцию `animate` вместе с ссылкой на себя. Когда анимация завершается, `animate` ещё раз вызывает функцию `animateOnClick`, и так по кругу. Если элемент массива в `animateOnClick` оказывается функцией - то сначала она выполняется, всё идёт на следующий круг.

Comment: Спасибо,вам.Но как сделать инициализацию карусели в последнем блоке?(Код исправил выше)

Comment: @JavAs обновил код

Comment: Я не понимаю как,но это работает, еще раз спасибо)

Comment: @JavAs по клику функция рекурсивно проходит по массиву blocks:

берет первый элемент массива, и передает его в функцию animate вместе с ссылкой на себя.

Когда анимация завершается animate ещё раз вызывает функцию animateOnClick, и так по кругу.

Если элемент массива в animateOnClick оказывается функцией - то сначала она выполняется, всё идёт на следующий круг.